# how to write if is not equal in blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have this in js file:

```
  isAdmin: function() {
    if (Meteor.user().roles[0] == "admin") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
},
```

In Html I want to say if admin ==false.how is it?

This is true condition : I want false

```
  {{#if isAdmin}}
       ...
  {{/if}}
```

Is it posible like this?

```
  {{#if !isAdmin}}
       ...
  {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is

```
{{#unless isAdmin}}
    ...
{{/unless}}
```

Have a look [here](http://blazejs.org/api/spacebars.html#If-Unless) at the docs.

Btw, if you are using the alanning:roles package, it includes a handy little helper for Blaze.

```
{{#unless isInRole 'admin'}}
    ...
{{/unless}}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes both is correct and also my own answer but I put green tick for yours because it is more general :)

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is this :

```
{{#if $eq isAdmin false}}
    ...
{{ /if }}
```

the other way is this:

```
Template.registerHelper('equals', function (a, b) {
  return a === b;
});
```

then in html :

```
{{#if equals isAdmin 'false'}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```